# GET api with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a web service link which I want to hit with different customerId in the form of

```
 http://apidev.myserver.com.au:8980/TestService/rest/TestService/jobs/bycustid/customerId
```

**how do I append the value of customerId?**

this is my base URL :

```
 http://apidev.myserver.com.au:8980/TestService/rest/TestService/
```

this is what my interface for calls look like :

```
interface CustomerJobs {
    @GET("jobs/bycustid/11726")
    Call<CustomerJobsPojo> getCustomerJobs();
}
```

Comment: The first example on Retrofit's site answers your question. `@Path`. Did you try?

Comment: dammit, feel so dumb! .. should i remove the question or let it be ?

Comment: It's a fine question, just remember to do some more research before you ask

Comment: my bad...... :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [doc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) says :

```
interface CustomerJobs {

    @GET("jobs/bycustid/{id}")
    Call<CustomerJobsPojo> getCustomerJobs(@Path("id") int id);

}
```

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: Might need to be `Integer id`.

Comment: @agonist_ - stackoverflow won't let me accept your answer in less than 10 minutes, although i knew at the very first sec that your answer right. i waited for 9 minutes and then got back to my work and forgot to accept :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `@Path` annotation

```
interface CustomerJobs {
    @GET("jobs/bycustid/{id}")
    Call<CustomerJobsPojo> getCustomerJobs(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can embed like

```
@GET("jobs/bycustid/{custId}")
     Call<CustomerJobsPojo> groupList(@Path("custId") int custId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use dynamic urls

```
interface CustomerJobs {

    @GET("jobs/bycustid/{customerid}")
    Call<CustomerJobsPojo> getCustomerJobs(@Path("id") int customerid);

}
```

Refer [this](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)